# Assemble a dataframe from two csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote the following code to form a data frame containing the energy consumption and the temperature. The data for each of the variables is collected from a different csv file:

```
def match_data():
pwr_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\X\Energy consumption per hour-data-2022-03-16 17_50_56_Edited.csv')
temp_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\X\temp.csv')
new_time = []
new_pwr = []
new_tmp = []
for i in range(1,len(pwr_data)):
    for j in range(1,len(temp_data)):
        if pwr_data['time'][i] == temp_data['Date'][j]:
            time = pwr_data['time'][i]
            pwr = pwr_data['watt_hour'][i]
            tmp = temp_data['Temp'][j]
            new_time.append(time)
            new_pwr.append(pwr)
            new_tmp.append(tmp)


return pd.DataFrame({'Time' : new_time,'watt_hour' : new_pwr,'Temp':new_tmp})
```

I was trying to collect data with matching time indices so that I can assemble them in a data frame.
The code works well but it takes time(43 seconds for around 1300 data points). At the moment I don't have much data but I was wondering if there was a more efficient and faster way to do so

Comment: Iteration is almost always going to be quite [slow compared to broadcasting](https://medium.com/@michaeleby1/broadcasting-versus-iteration-6c06539dc1d5). You're probably looking for the [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) method.

Answer (score 2):

Do the `pwr_data['time']` and `temp_data['Date]` columns have the same granularity?

If so, you can [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the two dataframes after reading them.

```
# read data
pwr_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\X\Energy consumption per hour-data-2022-03-16 17_50_56_Edited.csv')
temp_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\X\temp.csv')

# merge data on time and Date columns
# you can set the how to be 'inner' or 'right' depending on your needs
df = pd.merge(pwr_data, temp_data, how='left', left_on='time', right_on='Date')
```

Comment: thanks for answering. What do you mean by granularity? if you mean size then no. If you mean time increment between two data points then yeah. If i follow your code I would still need to match the time indices because the pwr_data has no values at certain time where the temp_data has values

Answer (score 1):

Just like @greco recommended this did the trick and in no time!

```
pd.merge(pwr_data,temp_data,how='inner',left_on='time',right_on='Date')
```

`'time'` and `Date` are the columns on which you want to base the merge.